# Laravel Excel Import

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как можно реализовать и можно ли вообще так делать. Нужно импортировать из excel файла в бд, с этим вроде разобрался. Но теперь нужно, чтобы информация заносилась в разные таблицы бд, связанные один к одному из одного файла. Особо информации не нашел в доках. 
Это метод контроллера, который импортирует в бд.

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'import_file' =>'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
        ]);



        $peoples = Excel::toArray(new PeopleImport(), $request->file('import_file'));
//        dd($peoples);
        foreach ($peoples[0] as $people){
            People::where('id', $people[0])->update([
                'name' => $people[1],
                'surname' => $people[2],
                'secondName' => $people[3],
                'email' => $people[4],
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->route('people')->with('success', 'Данные успешно получены!');
    }
```

Comment: Ну, импорт из файла предполагает, что Вы получаете входные данные и самостоятельно (программно) разносите их туда, где им место. Т.е. данные пришли, обработались и просто через модели разных таблиц вы записываете данные.
Документация https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev В том и сложность, я получаю коллекцию. И дальше не понимаю, как развести данные... Потому что он сразу прокидывает их в бд..

Comment: Дополните вопрос, приведите куски кода, которые занимаются импортом и т.п. Сейчас не понятно, как можно помочь

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev Я добавил метод контроллера добавления. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Смотри, строчка People::where('id', $people[0])->update([ говорит, что нужно обновить в таблице значение по id.

Я бы предложил в этом цикле не вставлять данные, а создать, например, 2 новых ассоциативных массива данных для каждой таблицы отдельно и  потом их вставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу попробуйте сделать так:

```
$peoples = Excel::toArray(new PeopleImport(), $request->file('import_file'));
$tablesForInsert = ['peoples', 'peoples2', 'peoples3']; //все таблицы в которые должны вставляться
foreach ($peoples[0] as $key => $people){
    DB::table($tableForInsert[$key])->where('id', $people[0])->update([
        'name' => $people[1],
        'surname' => $people[2],
        'secondName' => $people[3],
        'email' => $people[4],
    ]);
}
```

Данный код чисто для примера как разнести данные в разные таблицы! На бою соответственно проверяйте Ваши параметры которые скажут, что данные необходимо вставить именно в ту или иную таблицу. А лучше введите ещё коммиты для того чтобы при ошибке не получилось так что половина значений сохранилась а половина нет:

```
$peoples = Excel::toArray(new PeopleImport(), $request->file('import_file'));
$tablesForInsert = ['peoples', 'peoples2', 'peoples3']; //все таблицы в которые должны вставляться
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($peoples[0] as $key => $people){
        DB::table($tableForInsert[$key])->where('id', $people[0])->update([
            'name' => $people[1],
            'surname' => $people[2],
            'secondName' => $people[3],
            'email' => $people[4],
        ]);
    }
    DB::commit();
    return redirect()->route('people')->with('success', 'Данные успешно получены!');
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    redirect()->route('people')->with('errors', $e->getMessage());
}
```

В дополнение к комментариям:
Допустим В `people[5]` лежит значение для таблицы Rangs, `people[6]` лежит значение для таблицы Factory, `people[7]` лежит значение для таблицы Cities (какие колонки там не знаю, поэтому сами подгоните под свои нужны, покажу суть)
Остальное для таблицы peoples (1, 2, 3, 4 ...)

```
$peoples = Excel::toArray(new PeopleImport(), $request->file('import_file'));
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
foreach ($peoples[0] as $key => $people){
    $peopleTable = People::find($people[0]); // находим пользователя
    //Если связь 1 к одному как Вы говорите, то у Вас должны быть связаны уже модели! всё есть в документации, это уже к вопросу не относится
    $range = $peopleTable->range; //получаем связанную запись из первой таблицы
    $factory= $peopleTable->factory; //Таблица должна называться factories!! 
    //Читайте правила создания моделей и таблиц или жёстко задавайте таблицу при 
    //указании связи один к одному(Вы же написали что у Вас таблица Factory). Получаем связанную запись из второй таблицы
    $city= $peopleTable->city; //получаем связанную запись из третьей таблицы
    // Вставляем данные. Первая таблица
    $peopleTable->name = $people[1];
    $peopleTable->surname= $people[2];
    $peopleTable->secondName= $people[3];
    $peopleTable->email= $people[4];
    $peopleTable->save();
    //вторая таблица. (колонку сами подставите, везде буду `name` писать)
    $range->name = $people[5];
    $range->save();
    //Третья таблица. 
    $factory->name = $people[6];
    $factory->save();
    //Четвёртая таблица. 
    $city->name = $people[7];
    $city->save();
}
DB::commit();
return redirect()->route('people')->with('success', 'Данные успешно получены!');
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    redirect()->route('people')->with('errors', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я просто, не особо разбираюсь в этом. Только начал заниматься. А как мне в цикле указывать, чтобы например 5 столбец заносился в поле таблицы 2, а 6 в таблицу 3? Не совсем понятно....

Comment: @StanislavVolkov вот я и к тому же, я же не знаю по какому принципу Вы разносите данные по таблицам и за чем Вам это вообще надо. Поэтому я написал общий случай как одни данные можно в разные таблицы указать. Предположим Вам надо `$people[5]` добавлять в таблицу `peoples2` в какое0либо поле, тогда делайте `if` банальный. типо: if(isset($people[5]){ DB::table($tableForInsert[1]')...} и т.д.

Comment: Суть такова. Есть три таблицы Rangs, Factory, Cities. Они связанны один к одному с таблицей People. И нужно чтобы при загрузке excel, данные разносились по разным таблицам и при этом связь сохранялась. Такое вообще возможно сделать? Задание дали в ВУЗЕ...

Comment: @StanislavVolkov дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Данные приходят, а вот почему-то не перезаписывает и возвращает белую страницу... Проверял через dd, возращает null. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @StanislavVolkov кто возвращает null? https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one такие связи установлены между моделями? внешние ключи в таблицах есть которые связывают?

Comment: Да, все сделано как в доках. Например `$people->name` Null. Я кажется понял в чем проблема. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html Тут наверное надо добавить другие модели и поля к ним?

Comment: @StanislavVolkov это мой косяк!!!! $people = People::find($people[0]); тут мы переопределяем переменную цикла. Обновил ответ! Если будет так же, то тогда проверяйте что приходит в people[0] должен быть id реально существующего пользователя в таблице peoples. иначе будет null всегда!

Comment: Спасибо!!! Я очень Вам благодарен! Все заработало. Правда теперь когда в файле не совпадает число записей, то не работает... Если просто оставить импорт без цикла, то будет ругаться на дублированную запись...

Comment: @StanislavVolkov Просто добавьте проверки на существования тех или иных значений, как я писал во втором комментарии ( if(isset($people[5])...) то добавляете иначе пропускаете и т.д. тут уже фантазируйте как хотите! Если ответ помог можете отметить его как верный! Удачи Вам :)

Comment: Спасибо! А почему именно так? `if(isset($people[5])...)` Мне же по идеи по id проверять?

Comment: @StanislavVolkov как удобно проверяйте)) Суть в том, что надо просто делать проверку) а какими способами и что проверять Вы уже сами решаете и делаете как удобно

Comment: Дмитрий, как бы я не пытался, у меня не получается добавить новую запись после проверки(